# Dynamic Queue C++

Tags: c++

```
template<class T> 
class QueueD: public IQueue<T>{ 
    private: 
        Node<T> *QFront, *QRear; 
    public: 
        QueueD(): QFront(NULL), QRear(NULL){} 

        bool empty()const{
            return QFront==NULL;
        } 

        bool enqueue(const T &info){ 
            Node<T> *p=new Node<T>(info,NULL); 
            if(QFront==NULL)
                QFront=p; 
            else
                QRear->setNext(p); 
            QRear=p; 
            return true; 
        } 

        bool dequeue(T &info){ 
            if (empty()) return false; 
            else{ 
                info=QFront->getInfo(); 
                Node<T> *p=QFront; 
                if(QRear==QFront)
                    QRear=NULL;
                QFront=QFront->getNext(); 
                delete p; 
                return true; 
            } 
        } 
};

template<class T> 
class Node{ 
    private:
        T info; 
        Node *next; 

    public: 
        Node(const T &c, Node *p): info(c), next(p){
        } 

        Node *getNext()const{
            return next;
        } 

        void setNext(Node *p){
            next=p;
        } 

        T &getInfo(){
            return info;
        } 
};
```

I've been trying to understand C++ a little better, I was wondering if you guys could explain me a few lines of code that I do not understand here.

```
QFront=QFront->getNext();
```

How does QFront know which node is next? In the code it is only set for QRear.

```
if(QRear==QFront) {QRear=NULL;}
```

And why is this necessary?

edit: added Node template

Comment: Both the `QFront` and `QRear` variables are pointers to a `Node<T>`. Before being able to sensibly answer this question it would be nice to see `Node<T>` as well. But I'm ***assuming*** that `Node<T>` have a `next` and possibly a `prev` pointer.

Comment: `QFront` is set in `enqueue`:  `if(QFront==NULL) QFront=p;`

Comment: As for the second part of your question, as far as I can tell removing the line `if(QRear==QFront) {QRear=NULL;}` should have no impact on the class.

Comment: Your first answer lies in the implementation of `Node<T>`. Your second observation is astute. It isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When queue is empty `QFront == QRear`, so when you set next element for `QRear`, you'll effectively set up next element for QFront, too. That's how QFront knows which element is next.

I believe that setting `QRear` to `NULL` in `dequeue` is unnecessary since it's not used in `enqueue` in case of empty queue.